# Inserting AngularJS values into HTML table is not working

Tags: html, json, angularjs, controller

I am sending JSON to AngularJS through Node. I receive the correct data successfully in the controller which I print to the console. But when I try to fill the HTML table with the controller it doesn't work. I noticed that if I use the same fields but with "tasks" instead of "task" it will fill the "status" field into the table since the "tasks" object has a "status" field so the scope is technically working but I have no luck using "task" fields.

Controller

```
projectApp_TaskList.controller('getTaskListController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/getTaskList')
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.tasks = data;
            console.log($scope.tasks);
        });
});
```

Table

```
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Priotity</td>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td>Title</td>
                    <td>Limit Date</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                    <td>{{task.priority}}</td>
                    <td>{{task.status}}</td>
                    <td>{{task.title}}</td>
                    <td>{{task.limitDate}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

[Here's the link to the data I get on the console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0dvu.png)

[image]

Comment: What does data structure look like? Note the object you call `data` is a *response object* and the data you want is in `data.data`

Comment: I have added an image to show what I get from the console.log(data);.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object returned to `$http.get().then` is a *response object* that has multiple properties

The data you want is in a property `data` of that object

Try

```
$http.get('/getTaskList')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.tasks = response.data;
        console.log($scope.tasks);
    })
```

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks for the quick answer and help.